# My custom module does not show persian or arabic texts!

Tags: 7

I am developing a custom module. When I try to use Persian or Arabic text it does not show the text properly! The texts are shown in black square.
should I add anything?

[image: the picture]

As you see I installed Farsi language and menus are in Farsi but my custom text in module is not shown!

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail. Is this is a module you made? What is the purpose of the module? How is the content being displayed? What is displayed instead of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Locale module. Then you have to configure Arabic language.

- To get our languages hooked in, let's enable the core module, Locale.
- Go to Languages section in admin -  admin/config/regional/language:
- Click Add Language button
  [image]
- Then select Arabic form the drop down and save.
  [image]

That's all you have to do :)

Comment: i did that but still i have the same problem:  

http://i60.tinypic.com/33mljf7.png

as you see all menus are in farsi language except the text from inside my codes in module!!!

Comment: plz see this screen shot to see what i mean: http://oi57.tinypic.com/33as8xe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fonts rendering issue.
I want you to try this:

Insert some inline coding for you module and let me know if its working.

Example:`<p lang="ar" dir="rtl" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma;">your arabic text here</p>`